# Rename files, keep old incremented file order

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have used this to rename and increment file names with PowerShell:

```
$nr = 1
DIR | % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('File{0}.jpg' -f $nr++) }
```

It works but it seem it is renaming the files in the order of creation date.

I have 500 files each bulked in folders of 100 pics each, all with the order 1-100. The results would be `'picturename'1-500.jpg`.

So I need to be able to tell what the first number will be:

```
'screenshot (9).jpg'
'screenshot (10).jpg'
'screenshot (11).jpg'
etc
```

I need to rename them to:

```
'picture109.jpg'
'picture110.jpg'
'picture111.jpg'
etc
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not `sort` the results of `dir` before renaming the files to ensure you have the appropriate order ?

```
$nr = 1
dir | sort Name | % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('File{0}.jpg' -f $nr++) }
```

With PS complete syntax :

```
$nr = 1
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object Name | % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('File{0}.jpg' -f $nr++) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it but unfortunately it did not work. My original file2 still became file13 :/

Comment: I guess your sorting now is `screenshot (1)`, `screenshot (11)`, `screenshot (2)`, `screenshot (21)`, ... hard to fight against this ... You have to add leading 0's to restore the original order (if I understand the issue well).

Comment: The browser is sorting them properly 1,2,3,4 etc but I can see that the picture named pic2 has jumped down to pic13. The order the pictures was taken is pic1, pic13, pic2. (I had to rename a few of them manually to keep the order right). Hope that make sence